# How do I know what parameters I can call for WMS layers?

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, parameters

I'm trying to learn OpenLayers but the documentation is hard to understand.

For WMS layers, ex:

```
 var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS",
            "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0", { 
                "transparent":"true",
                "layers":"basic",
                "format":"image/png" },
              { "reproject":"true" }
              );
```

How do I know what all the possible parameters are?

Is there a list somewhere of all the parameters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Links to specifications for the various WMS versions are here

http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wms

and list all standard parameters.  Individual vendors have been known to add their own parameters on occasion.

Comment: Thanks. I searched but couldn't find the documentation anywhere. I'll be sure to bookmark that site.

Answer (score 1):

Someone can probably answer better than I but in QGIS I believe it tells you what parameters you can call when you connect to the WMS.